# Having trouble integrating angular js with wordpress using the rest api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, rest

Ok so I have included the following files into wordpress in the respective order:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/blog/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/angular-1.6.4/angular.min.js?ver=4.8.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/blog/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/angular-1.6.4/angular-resource.min.js?ver=4.8.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/blog/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/angular-1.6.4/angular-route.min.js?ver=4.8.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var localized = {"partials":"http:\/\/localhost\/blog\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/partials\/"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/blog/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/my-angular-scripts.js?ver=4.8.1'></script>
```

Inside `my-angular-scripts.js` I have the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myblog',['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/blog/', {
    templateUrl: localized.partials + 'test.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts').then(function(res){
    $scope.posts = res;
});
}]);
```

In the header template I have this:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> ng-app="myblog">
<head>
```

Now inside my front page template file I have this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
```

and my partial looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
<a href="{{ post.slug }}">
    {{ post.title }}
</a>
</div>
```

When I run it I get an error like this:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"\r\n  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"en\" xml:lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n<title>Object not found!</title>\r\n<link rev=\"made\" href=\"mailto:postmaster@localhost\" />\r\n<style type=\"text/css\"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ \r\n    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }\r\n    a:link { color: #0000CC; }\r\n    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}\r\n    span {font-size: smaller;}\r\n/*]]>*/--></style>\r\n</head>\r\n\r\n<body>\r\n<h1>Object not found!</h1>\r\n<p>\r\n\r\n\r\n    The requested URL was not found on this server.\r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    The link on the\r\n    <a href=\"http://localhost/blog/\">referring\r\n    page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of\r\n    <a href=\"http://localhost/blog/\">that page</a>\r\n    about the error.\r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n</p>\r\n<p>\r\nIf you think this is a server error, please contact\r\nthe <a href=\"mailto:postmaster@localhost\">webmaster</a>.\r\n\r\n</p>\r\n\r\n<h2>Error 404</h2>\r\n<address>\r\n  <a href=\"/\">localhost</a><br />\r\n  <span>Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30</span>\r\n</address>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n\r\n","status":404,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"wp-json/wp/v2/posts","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

Now if I go to this url: http://localhost/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
I get some JSON objects but only 10 or so, there are > 300 posts in the database.

Anyone know how to solve this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there was a few things wrong here.

The link for the rest api json data was wrong and the way I was injecting the result data into posts was wrong.
I used this link:

```
`blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`
```

and this code to get the results and inject into the controller:

```
$http.get('blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').then(function(res){
    $scope.posts = res.data;
});
```

Also instead of using the partial I just used this on my template front page:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <a href="{{ post.link }}">
            {{ post.title.rendered }}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason i'm getting 10 posts instead of >300 is because by default the rest api will only return 10. Unless I specify more.

More info can be [found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/).

I hope this helps someone else :)